# Script to cat log files that have been rotated

Tags: bash, scripts

I frequently cat a load of log files into a single file.  Eg the files are of the form `ABC_0.txt`, up to `ABC_99.txt`.

What I normally have to do is rename the single digit numbers so the number is prefixed with a zero for the cat to work (eg `ABC_0.txt` to `ABC_9.txt` have to be renamed to `ABC_00.txt` to `ABC_09.txt`).

Then I just do this:

```
cat *.txt > all.txt
```

which works fine.

I often have the problem that the log files are rotated and actually the earliest log file is `ABC_14.txt` for example.  So the cat line above will have the contents of `all.txt` out of sequence.

Any ideas how to basically start from `ABC_14.txt` onwards?

To clarify my question, I have log files cat0.txt to cat9.txt but I want the cat to be like this:

```
cat cat7.txt cat8.txt cat9.txt cat0.txt cat1.txt cat2.txt cat3.txt cat4.txt cat5.txt cat6.txt >all.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `cat` the files ordered by their modification dates you can do the following:

```
ls -tr ABC_* | xargs cat
```

Which will first sort the files by their modification time, followed by `cat` command

> ```
> man ls
> -t    sort by modification time, newest first
> -r    reverse order while sorting
> ```

`ls -tr` will result with sort by modification time, oldest first

---

If you want to `cat` the files in a reverse order you can do the following:

```
ls -r ABC_* | xargs cat
```

Which will first reverse the order of the files, followed by `cat` command

for example

```
$ ls -r ABC_*
ABC_03  ABC_02  ABC_01
```

Assuming that the content of each ABC_number is the number itself, the output will be:

```
$ ls -r ABC_* | xargs cat
03
02
01
```

Comment: A archiving tool which combines all the files into one may mean this won't work, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bash globes for this purpose:

```
cat ABC_[0-9]*.txt
```

which only cats files started with the name "ABC_" followed by one number and some character then ended to `.txt`.